# Identifying consecutive cells for which the value changes (e.g. from 1 to 2)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

(In excel) So I have this list of numbers associated either with choice "1" or "2", so next to that list is a list of only 2's and 1's. I want to find the "turning" point, that is, the instance when 1 becomes 2 or 2 becomes 1, and the numbers associated to each "turning point". If it can help to visualize it: I may have five 2's, and then suddenly three 1's, so I want to pinpoint the value associated to the last "2" (in cell 5) and of the first "1" (in cell 6). Note that this change of value happens more than once throughout the list...any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Okay, so here's my problem, the data I'm playing with has been filtered, that said, the cells do not appear in consecutive order (1,2,3,4...) but rather in a disrupted way (1,5,6,9,14,... for example). In that case, the formula doesn't work out...is there either a way to "re-number" the cells, or another formula? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way. The formula in cell **C2** is:

```
=IF(OR(A2<>A3,A1<>A2),B2,0)
```

Screenshot below:

[image]

If you were plotting the points I'd suggest using `,na())` at the end of the formula rather than `,0)` because graphs will ignore this error but plots zeros

Comment: Thanks! I think I'm going somewhere with this!

Comment: Okay, so here's my problem, the data I'm playing with has been filtered, that said, the cells do not appear in consecutive order (1,2,3,4...) but rather in a disrupted way (1,5,6,9,14,... for example). In that case, the formula doesn't work out...is there either a way to "re-number" the cells, or another formula? thanks!

Comment: Maybe just sort your data before applying the formulas - select your data and click on "Data" on the ribbon then "Sort". Let me know if that works

Comment: It does not seem to work...I really want to switch the scale on the side back to "1,2,3..." The only option I found for now was pasting my date into a new worksheet and then applying the formulas

Comment: Hi @SarahR. It's really difficult to suggest without seeing a screenshot of your problem. Pleased to hear you've found a solution. If you have, please  select the tick to the left of my original answer to close the question.